# How to change the default look of a button or a form? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to change the appearance of the the form and the buttons, boxes etc which are laid on it. In java we can do that using Numbuzz look and feel or swing apperance. But i dont want to use the same traditional look of XP or any other OS which im gonna install my application, any one has an idea??

Comment: With WinForms, I think your only option is to create custom controls to replicate the behavior IIRC.  WinForms is just a wrapper to use the Windows API which itself wasn't very customizable.

Comment: @Jeff If i want to cusomize them according to my requirement, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could give [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) a try and see if it's what you are looking for.

I'm using this library myself for application's design and i found it pretty cool. It has a lot of already made themes(like outlook controls...).

hope this helps

Comment: This looks good but, is there any free application similar to this.

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah sorry i dont know any free one.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use WPF, WPF has been designed to make look and feel easily customizable.

or use vendor products like Infragistics WinForms (which allows you to specify Stylesheet kind of behaviour (search for infragisticsc stylesheet "ISL" ))